# Proper replacement for CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND when upgrading to Celery 4.x for django 1.11

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

In trying to replace django-celery and upgrade celery to 4.x from an inherited project, I'm having hard time understanding the real changes to effect.

Celery is already setup as the project uses 3.x, however in removing djcelery from the app, I come across this:

`CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'`

Reading the [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.0.html), I'm more confused about using result_backend or celery.backend.database or which:

`CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'celery.backends.database'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'beat_scheduler'` OR

`CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: result_backend
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER: beat_scheduler`

I'm new to Celery, still getting familiar with the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Celery 4 changed their settings as follows: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

> The major difference between previous versions, apart from the lower
>   case names, are the renaming of some prefixes, like celerybeat_ to
>   beat_, celeryd_ to worker_, and most of the top level celery_ settings
>   have been moved into a new task_ prefix.
>
> Celery will still be able to read old configuration files, so there’s
>   no rush in moving to the new settings format.

The expectation is that you use `result_backend` instead of `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`. Full mapping of old upper case settings to new ones are documented here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#new-lowercase-settings

In other words, `resut_backend` is the new name of the key, NOT the new *recommended value*. It is the **replacement for the left hand side of your assignment**. These are equivalent:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
result_backend = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

Likewise these are equivalent:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
beat_scheduler = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

Comment: Ooh I see the left hand assignment replacement. However, I'm trying to get rid of djcelery as well, because Celery does not need it anymore. What is the proper right hand values?

Comment: I&#39;m not sure about this. I can try looking it up, but it is another question altogether :)

Comment: I guess I'll have to pose a new question as well... :)

Comment: See this perhaps: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#database-backend-settings